# Firebase Authentication on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and I'm looking for an updated tutorial link or document that shows how to get Firebase Authentication working with Xamarin.Form or if someone can supply a GitHub link with an example of how to get firebase auth working on Xamarin.forms with Visual Studios 2019?

Note: I've followed the tutorial from https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-auth-on-xamarin-forms-171432aa3d76 but it doesn't work.

Comment: It would be better if you tell us where it doesn't work and share us some codes or what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have this link for you. 
https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/26/firebase-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/

Try it and let me know if it will be working or not.

Answer (score 0):

this one really helped me, it is a perfect example

https://github.com/saipedireddi1/xamarin-example

using FirebaseAuthentication.net nugget